# How to wait until an object has been removed/deleted from a webpage in UFT?

Tags: vba, wait, hp-uft

In our web application there are tables where users can enter/delete data.

Checking once something has been added, I'd like UFT to wait until the element is no longer on the page before continuing. Each time a row, or element is deleted from the webpage the page refreshes, often UFT will try to continue thus causing the test to fail.

It seems `.WaitProperty "visible", false, 3000` waits for the timeout to complete and then continues.

I'm looking for something similar to `.StalenessOf` in Selenium.

Looking to have the wait be more dynamic to make these tests run as fast as possible. If we end up using UFT I'll have a very large test suite and would like to reduce the amount of hard-coded waits, and avoid them if I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UFT supports  [`Exist` to check if an object exists](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/15.0-15.0.2/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#Common_Methods_and_Properties/Common_Methods_and_Properties.html#Exist).

You can pass a zero timeout and wait until the object doesn't exist.

```
While Obj.Exist(0)
   Wait 1
WEnd
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I did notice I needed to turn off the smart identification on elements that were similarly named. However, this seems to work just fine, I appreciate it, have a great day!